# Interpret smartctl -a output

Tags: smart, smartctl

Please help me understand this

```
root@bdb16e4bb2e3:/opt/scrutiny# smartctl --all /dev/sdb
smartctl 7.2 2020-12-30 r5155 [aarch64-linux-5.15.0-1024-raspi] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-20, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     SanDisk based SSDs
Device Model:     SanDisk pSSD
Serial Number:    <removed>
LU WWN Device Id: <removed>
Firmware Version: 6EB 1030
User Capacity:    128,043,712,512 bytes [128 GB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Rotation Rate:    Solid State Device
Form Factor:      1.8 inches
TRIM Command:     Available, deterministic
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ACS-2 T13/2015-D revision 3
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.0, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Tue Feb 21 15:00 2023 PST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: FAILED!
Drive failure expected in less than 24 hours. SAVE ALL DATA.
See vendor-specific Attribute list for failed Attributes.

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                                        was never started.
                                        Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                                        without error or no self-test has ever 
                                        been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:                (  120) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:                    (0x51) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                                        No Auto Offline data collection support.
                                        Suspend Offline collection upon new
                                        command.
                                        No Offline surface scan supported.
                                        Self-test supported.
                                        No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                                        Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                                        power-saving mode.
                                        Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                                        General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:        (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (  41) minutes.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 1
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0002   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       4
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0002   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       120
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0002   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
165 Total_Write/Erase_Count 0x0002   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       2054
171 Program_Fail_Count      0x0002   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
172 Erase_Fail_Count        0x0002   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       4
173 Avg_Write/Erase_Count   0x0002   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       41
174 Unexpect_Power_Loss_Ct  0x0002   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0002   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   092   008   000    Old_age   Always       -       8 (Min/Max -4/33)
230 Perc_Write/Erase_Count  0x0002   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       136
232 Perc_Avail_Resrvd_Space 0x0003   000   100   005    Pre-fail  Always   FAILING_NOW 0
234 Perc_Write/Erase_Ct_BC  0x0002   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       10000
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0002   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
242 Total_LBAs_Read         0x0002   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0

SMART Error Log not supported

SMART Self-test Log not supported

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 0
Note: revision number not 1 implies that no selective self-test has ever been run
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

232 Perc_Avail_Resrvd_Space 0x0003   000   100   005    Pre-fail  Always   FAILING_NOW 0 is failing, should I be worried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By my understanding - yes.

Reserved blocks are finished. And if any block fail the SSD controller have no available block to replace it. The best you can do is to backup all the information you have and replace the disk. Because with SSD disks the case is they stop at once, entirely and you get very small chance to recovery some information in recovery labs.

Comment: I see... thanks for the quick help.

Comment: Any other tool that I can use to validate the same? (i'm using ubuntu on raspberrypi 4)

Comment: @pyofey, I am not aware of other tools, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Is that a Sandisk Extreme Pro USB drive? I have one with strikingly similar SMART stats

```
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0002   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       4
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0002   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0002   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
165 Total_Write/Erase_Count 0x0002   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       4
171 Program_Fail_Count      0x0002   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
172 Erase_Fail_Count        0x0002   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
173 Avg_Write/Erase_Count   0x0002   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       1
174 Unexpect_Power_Loss_Ct  0x0002   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0002   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   092   008   000    Old_age   Always       -       8 (Min/Max 0/33)
230 Perc_Write/Erase_Count  0x0002   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       3
232 Perc_Avail_Resrvd_Space 0x0003   000   100   005    Pre-fail  Always   FAILING_NOW 0
234 Perc_Write/Erase_Ct_BC  0x0002   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       10000
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0002   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
242 Total_LBAs_Read         0x0002   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
```

This is not a heavily used drive and I'm skeptical that it is failing. One issue with SMART stats is that they are not sufficiently standardized and manufacturers are free to use them as they wish. I wonder if that's the situation here.

Seems like a related bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/smartmontools/+bug/2000656